# How do you add support for (server side) SSL/TLS mining?

Tags: privacy, mining-pools, mining-pool-setup

Basically, the title. I run a small pool and want to add SSL/TLS support for miners. I tried making `openssl` manage the connection and pipe it locally to the correct port, but that doesn't work.

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the *stunnel* program to do that (https://www.stunnel.org).

It waits for incoming SSL/TLS connections and redirects the decrypted data streams to a local port (e.g. a server that doesn't support SSL/TLS on its own).